# AppFuse 3 does not deploy to Tomcat 8

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, appfuse

I have downloaded AppFuse version 3.0 following the quick start guide here: http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart

my set up string is this:
mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.appfuse.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=appfuse-basic-spring-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=3.0.0 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=myproject -DarchetypeRepository=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/appfuse

I am able to also successfully run: mvn appfuse:full-source

The application then starts fine with: mvn jetty:run

I then can successfully run: mvn package

Here is where the good luck runs out...

When I try to deploy the resulting .war to Tomcat 8, it doesn't deploy.  No error message, it just goes to the generic "problem loading page" message.  Upon checking tomcat logs, I see no error messages.  Tomcat is still running happily with no reference to a failed deployment.

Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: What's the error you see in Tomcat 8? Can you try with the 3.5.0-SNAPSHOT release? It's code complete, we're just updating the documentation now. http://appfuse.547863.n4.nabble.com/Update-on-3-5-0-Release-td4657695.html

Comment: I have run the 3.5.0-SNAPSHOT release.  It looks like the resulting pom.xml is quite different.  I have been looking for the database connection string so I can put in the correct password.  It looks like there are some added properties files, and I see references to "jdbc.password" ... but I don't see where that gets set.

Comment: You can override the default password by adding a <jdbc.password> property to the <properties> section of your pom. These changes are described in the following blog post: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/appfuse_reduced. As a result of these changes, most poms have gone from 800 lines to < 100!

Comment: Thank you.  I am able to run this version in Tomcat 8.  It worked first time as soon as I added the password change.  My goal is to convert an AppFuse 2 app to this new style.  It looks like it might be a bit messy... but I hope to be able to make the change because the new version looks to be very nice.